# Hyperlinks in TextBox/ListBox ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, hyperlink, listbox

I have read some posts online that say you can not include Hyperlinks in Textbox or listboxes in html. I am reading text from a DB and part of that text are hyperlinks to articles. What control should I use therefore to display text in a scroll-able control and be able to include hyperlinks that will lead to other sites on the web?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.aspx) or a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx) and store the hyperlink as the value, and add a javascript `change` event that will redirect them to the value (hyperlink) of the selected item... or do it on postback.
2. You can use a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) and use regular hyperlinks. If you want it "scroll-able", put it in a container of fixed height with an `overflow:scroll;`
3. You can use a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) if you have many items that aren't a good fit from dropdown, etc.

It really depends... you'll need to try something and if you have problems with code, come back and ask a question that can be answered with code.